# File drag-and-drop not working with knockout.js

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm trying to achieve a file drag-and-drop with knockout.js.

This is my html:

```html
<div type="text" id="filedrag" class="" data-bind="event: {drop: function (data,e) { $root.insertFile(e,data);} }">
    <div id="messages"></div>
</div>
```

And this my JS:

```
self.insertFile = function(e, data) {
    console.log("insertfile called");
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
};
```

I copied the code from [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBJd2/1/). I don't quite see the difference between that one and mine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is it not working? Error message? A jsfiddle with your code may help.

Comment: Second @manji, except please use a fiddle only for *support*: always include the full repro *in* the question. (Or use Stack Snippets instead of jsfiddle.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you need to have a dragover event where you cancel the default behaviour.
The cancellation of the dragover event is needed to allow drop.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover.

I have created a fiddle with your code, updated with an dragover event where you cancel default behaviour.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JBJd2/10/

HTML:

```
<div type="text" id="filedrag" class="drop_zone" data-bind="event: {
    drop:       function (data,e) { $root.insertFile(e,data);},
    dragover:   function(data, e){ $root.dragover(e);} 
}"> 

    <div id="messages"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
self.insertFile  = function(e, data) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("insertfile called");
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
};

self.dragover = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: aah, thanx a lot! Thought, I could just use the drop event. Thanx!!